# Do these joins change anything

Tags: mariadb, join

I have a request which looks like this :

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B
    ON A.id_B = B.id
  INNER JOIN C
    ON B.id_C = C.id
```

`A.id_B` and `B.id_C` are foreign keys `NOT NULL`

For me the `INNER JOIN` are totally useless and just slows down the query but a colleague told me that in certain specific case it removes some rows from A. He could not show me any of those cases and I could not find any either.

I wanted to know if the `INNER JOIN` really are useful or if they can be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE a (id INT, id_b INT);
> CREATE TABLE b (id INT, id_c INT);
> CREATE TABLE c (id INT);
> INSERT INTO c VALUES (1), (1), (2), (3), (3), (4), (6);
> INSERT INTO b VALUES (1,1), (1,1), (2,2), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5);
> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.*
> FROM a
>   INNER JOIN b
>     ON a.id_b = b.id
>   INNER JOIN c
>     ON b.id_c = c.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id_b
> -: | ---:
>  1 |    1
>  1 |    1
>  1 |    1
>  1 |    1
>  2 |    2
>  2 |    2
>  3 |    3
>  3 |    3
>  4 |    4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=925921f7d49e6b43a8a23e393919733a)*

- Row with value `1` is returned 4 times (2 matches in table `b` and 2 matches in table `c` gives 4 combinations).
- Row with value `2` is returned 2 times (2 matches in table `b`).
- Row with value `3` is returned 2 times (2 matches in table `c`).
- Row with value `4` is returned once (no duplicates in joining chain).
- Row with value `5` is not returned because there is no match in table `c`.
- Row with value `6` is not returned because there is no match in table `b`.
- Row with value `7` is not returned because there is no match in tables `b` and `c`.

You may test the fiddle - remove table `c` joining (or both `b` and `c` joinings), look how the output changes, and think why so...

Answer (score 0):

The only way that they would remove rows from the result set is if the foreign key relationships were *broken*.

Question: Are they actually *enforced* by foreign keys?

Was that [once] the *intention* but, for whatever reason, it was never implemented? (Sadly, it happens)

If these really are "proper" foreign keys then yes, the joins are redundant.

If in doubt, check it for yourself:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id_B = B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON B.id_C = C.id

WHERE B.id IS NULL 
   OR C.id IS NULL
```

If you get zero rows back, then everything is as it *should* be and the joins can be safely removed.